# How to control podman container log behaviour (ctr.log)

Tags: logging, podman

My `/var` ran full, the culprit was `/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/<container-hash>/userdata/ctr.log` of my gitlab container, which was 11GB.

I searched the documentation/interwebs in vain for any info on

1. is it safe to delete the ctr.log (on a running container)?
2. is there a `podman` command to manage the log (e.g. clean, keep last x MB or days)?
3. do the `--logdriver` and `--logopt` options to `podman-run` control/affect `ctr.log`, or is this some extra log?
4. if (through (3)) I can turn off logging, would I still see logs when attaching to the running container?

Regarding (1) it appears the answer is "yes", deleting `ctr.log` and restarting the container just made a new `ctr.log`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to 1,2,3 or 4 but it prevents filling the disk space which seems the objective of the question.

see https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019954

> Create or edit `/etc/containers/containers.conf` for podman running as root, or `$HOME/.config/container/containers.conf` for root-less containers, to contain "`log_size_max=SIZE`" in the `[containers]` section, with SIZE being the maximum size in bytes for the log files. For example:
>
> ```
> [containers]
> log_size_max=10485760
> ```
>
> to set a maximum log size of 10 MiB. Afterwards, restart all containers to activate the change.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your reply as well as in the article.
It should state `$HOME/.config/containers/containers.conf`